# sign in with slack and validate request from firebase backend for the angular app

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-authentication, slack-api, angular6

i have built a webapp using angular material and firebase functions + realtime DB as the backend.  I am using slack "Sign in with Slack" API oauth flow. All works well and i am able to generate a accessToken in the backend which i can store against the user in the realtime DB. Once that is done i make a redirect call to my angular app on the dashboard page. Currently i am passing userid in the redirect url which i use to drive user to dashboard and show his data.

This functionally works fine but is a big security issue. As i can directly type the redirect url and boom. I am in the dashboard.

So, how do i solve this? What should i be doing in the url redirect that is secure and validates the response is the the result of a valid request?

Comment: Encrypt the Token when passing it to the url?

Comment: sure though using what? and how does it prevent from anyone else using the same url as is? it's my app that knows how to decrypt. The one directly using it does not need to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Slack OAuth SDK but in general, this is true for all OAuth providers. Ideally, at the point where you redirect to your callback URL with the slack authorization code and you exchange the auth code for a Slack access token before returning that access token to the client, you call the Slack API to get the Slack user ID with the access token and then mint a Firebase custom token with that uid. You then return that custom token to the client and `signInWithCustomToken`. Make sure you are checking the `state` field (which you set when started the Slack sign in) along with Auth code to verify that the flow started and ended on the same device.

Comment: Your last part of response is exactly what i am looking for.  More details or sample on how the firebase custom token is passed?